# Once function keeps executing

Tags: javascript, events, listener, addeventlistener

I wrote a once event listener function but it keeps executing as usual event listener not once [here](http://codepen.io/nikos_efthias/pen/vNXOmG?editors=001) is the working code and below the function i wrote

```
window.once=function(event,cb){
  function ccb(e){
    event=e||window.event;
    if(event){
      cb(event);
      this.removeEventListener(event,ccb);
    }
  }
  this.addEventListener(event,ccb);
}

window.Element.prototype.once=function(event,cb){
  function ccb(e){
    event=e||window.event;
    if(event){
      cb(event);
      this.removeEventListener(event,ccb);
    }
  }
  this.addEventListener(event,ccb);
}
```

Comment: `once` isn't built into JavaScript - are you using any libraries?

Comment: that is teh point i am extending the natve code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting this problem because you are trying to remove the `MouseEvent` event, instead of the `MouseEvent`. To clarify this, try this:

```
....
function ccb(e){
    event=e||window.event;
    if(event){
       console.log(event);
    }
}
....
```

logs the event `MouseEvent` itself, while

```
window.once=function(event,cb){
    function ccb(e){
       ....
    }
    console.log(event)
    this.addEventListener(event,ccb);
}
```

logs the string `Click`

The solution for this is to access the key `type` from your mouseevent, e.g.

```
window.once=function(event,cb){
    function ccb(e){
        event=e||window.event;
        if(event){
            cb(event);
            this.removeEventListener(event.type,ccb);
       }
    }
    this.addEventListener(event,ccb);
}
```